# does not contain a definition for 'done'/'then'

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

While using **CreateFileAsync** winRT APi i am getting this error;

> '`Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>`' does not contain a definition for '`done`' and no extension method '`done`' accepting a first argument of type '`Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Why?

The example from msdn is thesame as well [msdn API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241633.aspx#Y314)

Comment: That example is in JavaScript, that's why it doesn't work in C#.

Comment: but the syntax is in C# isn't it??? its also in c++ and VB! as shown in the link page!

Comment: Yeah, the Syntax section is correct C#. But for some reason, that example is only in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lise I said in a comment, the example is in JavaScript, not C#. The proper way to use asynchronous methods from C# is to use `await`:

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");
// Your code
```

This code must be in a method marked as `async`.